# Remove top rule of `ruled` algorithm2e

Tags: rules, algorithm2e

I'd like to use similar styles for pseudocode/algorithms and listings using the `algorithm2e` package. Therefore I need a line above and below the algorithm but not above the caption. Haven't found any solution so far.

[image: Example]

Adjusted several configurations like the style of the line numbers and the caption, but yeah.. cannot getting rid off the line above:

```
\setlength{\algoheightrule}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont}
\SetAlgoCaptionLayout{centerline}
\SetNlSty{ttfamily}{}{}
\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize{-3}
```

Thanks a lot!

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{algorithm}
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX}
    \caption{How to write algorithms}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete, yet minimal, code?

Comment: @Bernard added a mwe for the algorithm stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the algorithms using the `plainruled` style - two single rules, one above, one below the algorithm - and adjust the way the algorithm caption is set; default is `under`, so we change that to `above` (not `top`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  plainruled,
  linesnumbered,
  noline
]{algorithm2e}

\setlength{\algoheightrule}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont}
\SetAlgoCaptionLayout{centerline}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\makeatletter
% Add adjustments to plainruled format
\def\@algocf@capt@plainruled{above}
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@plainruled}{%
  \vskip\AlCapSkip%
  \box\algocf@capbox%
  \vskip 5\algoheightrule}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwData{This text}
  \KwResult{How to write algorithm with \LaTeX}
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

A minor adjustment is included to add a space between the caption and the algorithm's top rule.

Comment: works like a charm except the indentation. Do you know a way to left align the text at the really left side? Like in the listing above. So that the line numbering are outside the box.

Comment: Done by `\setlength{\algomargin}{-0pt}`