# Adjust caption of algorithm2e using own macro

Tags: macros, captions, algorithm2e

I have a document with a few tables that have their captions formatted like this

[image]

which I achieved using

```
\usepackage[format=plain, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=true]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline, textfont=it, singlelinecheck=false, margin=1em}
```

and I would like to use the same layout for algorithms. I did find out from the package-readme and [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418783/remove-top-rule-of-ruled-algorithm2e) that I need

```
\usepackage[plainruled]{algorithm2e}
```

to remove the top rule above the caption and get this:

[image]

Next, I understand I need to define my own macro `style` to be able to use

```
\SetAlgoCaptionLayout{style}
```

but I am confused how to create the macro and how to left-align, use normalfont in footnotesize for the algorithm heading, insert the line break, and italicize the caption text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[plainruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
{\footnotesize
\caption{An example}
some text\;
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, could you post a complete compilable example so we can help you on this ?

Comment: of course — apologies, I had forgotten but added one now!

Comment: Maybe this ? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[algoruled]{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\AlCapNameFnt}{\normalfont\itshape}
\renewcommand{\AlCapFnt}{\normalfont}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
{\footnotesize
\caption{An example}
some text\;
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}`

Comment: Unfortunately not with `plainrule`, where `\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{\\} ` does not work and the caption is below the body and centered. I use `plainruled` to get rid of the top rule above the caption. Is there perhaps a way of getting this done in `algoruled`? That would solve things!

Comment: @bumblebee: You want the algorithm caption to resemble the table though, right? `plainruled` puts the caption at the bottom, which is different from the visual of putting the (table) caption at the top.

Comment: Exactly, I would like it to resemble the table. I considered `plainruled` the starting point because it only boxes the body into rules and has the caption outside. If there are other ways, I would be just as happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. You can redefine the function defining the top rule. It is not perfect, but works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[algoruled]{algorithm2e}

% Removes the top rule above caption see l.2531 of algorithm2e.sty
\makeatletter
\def\@algocf@pre@algoruled{}%
\makeatother
% Changes the caption font to italic
\renewcommand{\AlCapNameFnt}{\footnotesize\itshape}
% Removes bold font Algorithm
\renewcommand{\AlCapFnt}{\footnotesize\normalfont}
% Replaces ":" with a linebreak after Algorithm n°xxx
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
{\footnotesize
\caption{An example}
some text\;
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! I will edit your code to insert `\footnotesize` into the font setups and post new output so it matches the OP. Thanks!

Comment: @bumblebee you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

The following also adds the `\footnotesize` font size to your `algorithm` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\SetAlCapFnt{\normalfont\footnotesize}% Set caption font
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{\par\nobreak}% Set caption separator
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\unskip\itshape\footnotesize}% Set caption name font
\makeatletter
\def\@algocf@pre@ruled{}% Remove rule above caption
\let\old@algocf@start\@algocf@start
\renewcommand{\@algocf@start}{\old@algocf@start\footnotesize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An example}
  some text\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming the `\footnotesize` in the `\SetAlCapFnt{}` and the `SetAlCapNameFnt{}` are redundant then?

Comment: @bumblebee: No, since the default ads `\normalfont` if I recall, so you have to set it explicitly.

Comment: I am afraid I don’t see the difference between this and the previous answer then.

Comment: @bumblebee: The difference is you don't have to use `\footnotesize` explicitly with every `algorithm`. It seemed like you wanted everything (the algorithm caption and body) in `\footnotesize`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Now I understand, thanks very much!